# How can I efficiently unit test this complex query?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, castle-windsor, moq

I work on a large application. The code base is mostly divided into various tasks, and each task receives its dependencies (usually repositories) via DI, such as this simplified, theoretical class:

```
public class EmailTasks
{
    public EmailTasks( IUserRepository userRepository )
    {
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    private readonly IUserRepository UserRepository;

    public void SendNoticeEmail( DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
    {
        var users = GetUsersWithNotices( minDate, maxDate, etc... );

        // send email to each user
    }

    private IEnumerable<User> GetUsersWithNotices( DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
    {
        return UserRepository.FindAll( u => u.Active && !u.Whatever
                                            && u.JoinDate > minDate && u.JoinDate < maxDate
                                            && u.Notices.Any( n => n.Active && !n.Something
                                                                   && Whatever
                                                                   && etc... ) );
    }
}
```

My task is to figure out how to unit test `GetUsersWithNotices`. The test needs to verify that the method only returns users that meet the criteria.

I'm not sure where to start. With Moq, I can verify that the `FindAll` method is called:

```
[TestClass]
public class EmailTasksTest
{
    private Mock<IUserRepository> userRepositoryMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SendNoticeEmailTest()
    {
        var minDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays( -30 );
        var maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays( 30 );
        var user1 = new Mock<User>();
        var user2 = new Mock<User>();

        userRepositoryMock.Setup( r => r.FindAll( It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>() ) )
                          .Returns( new List<User>
                                        {
                                            user1Mock.Object,
                                            user2Mock.Object
                                        }.AsQueryable() )
                          .Verifiable();

        var tasks = new EmailTasks( userRepositoryMock.Object );
        task.SendNoticeEmail( minDate, maxDate, etc... );

        userRepositoryMock.Verify();
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't test that the users meet the criteria. Any tests I write against the results from mocking up `UserRepository.FindAll` will only validate what I mocked up.

So how can I efficiently unit test this complex query?

*EDIT*

I attempted to separate the business logic from the query:

```
public class EmailTasks
{
    public EmailTasks( IUserRepository userRepository )
    {
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    private readonly IUserRepository UserRepository;

    public void SendNoticeEmail( DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
    {
        var users = GetUsersWithNotices( minDate, maxDate, etc... );

        // send email to each user
    }

    private IEnumerable<User> GetUsersWithNotices( DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
    {
        return UserRepository.FindAll( u => UserIsValidForNotice( u, minDate, maxDate, etc... ) );
    }

    private bool UserIsValidForNotice( User user, DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
    {
        return user.Active && !user.Whatever
               && u.JoinDate > minDate && u.JoinDate < maxDate
               && u.Notices.Any( n => n.Active && !n.Something
                                 && Whatever
                                 && etc... ) );
    }
}
```

This causes NHibernate to throw an exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Boolean UserIsValidForNotice(User, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)
  Source=Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.InvokeRealProxy(RealProxy realProxy, WcfInvocation wcfInvocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.<>c__DisplayClass1.<PerformInvocation>b__0(WcfInvocation wcfInvocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.ApplyChannelPipeline(Int32 policyIndex, WcfInvocation wcfInvocation, Action`1 action)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ApplyChannelPipeline>b__3()
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.RefreshChannelPolicy.Apply(WcfInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.ApplyChannelPipeline(Int32 policyIndex, WcfInvocation wcfInvocation, Action`1 action)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.PerformInvocation(IInvocation invocation, Action`1 action)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.PerformInvocation(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Async.WcfRemotingAsyncInterceptor.PerformInvocation(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Proxies.IEmailServiceProxy.SendNoticeEmail()
       at [Excised]
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I guess it's too complex for NHibernate to convert to SQL.

Comment: Personally (because there are probably many solutions to this), I'd create a new layer between your repo and your domain logic. This layer would encapsulate all those queries (which, alone, are easy to test). Or maybe even add that query logic directly in your repo. In EmailTask you would be able to abstract this query logic (by mocking the new layer) to have actions that are easy to test. Because currently, your class is not "doing only one thing" and that's what is hard to test.

Comment: The problem with extracting any part of the query is it causes NHibernate to throw an exception. I'll edit my question to reflect what I just tried.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]
I did some additional research and ended up asking the same question and received some good answers: 
[How can I stub an interface method using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102120/how-can-i-stub-an-interface-method-using-moq)

This might be a good place to use a stub instead of Moq like follows:

```
public class StubRepo : IUserRepository
{
    public IList<User> PersonList { get; set; }

    public IList<User> FindAll(Func<User, bool> q)
    {
        return PersonList.Where(q).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in a dummy list of people and verify that the ones returned satisfy your criteria. Since GetUsersWithValidNotices is private, you would use Moq to verify that your email sending logic was called only once. It would look something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Arrange
        var userList = new List<User>();
        userList .Add(new User { Name="Mike", Active = false });
        userList .Add(new User { Name="Mary", Active = true });
        var stubRepo = new StubRepo{ PersonList = userList});

        var emailSender = Mock<IEmailSender>();

         var emailTask = new EmailTask(stubRepo);
        emailTask.EmailSender = emailSender.Object;


        //Action
        emailTask.SendNoticeEmail(.....);

        //Assert - Verify email only sent to the one active user
        emailSender.Verify(x => x.SendEmail(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once())

    }
```

This will test that the logic of your query is correct, however, a huge caveat is the fact that specific functions in your query may not be able to be converted to a SQL query, so your query would work on the dummy list but may throw an exception when run against an actual database. There is definitely value in unit testing this to make sure all of your conditions are correct, but you absolutely need to integration test it against a real database as well.

[Edit]
I would go back to your original method setup shown below. While this query is large, It shouldn't give you any issues, because all of your tests are relatviely simple boolean operations. Then you can test the whole thing by following this post: [How can I stub an interface method using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102120/how-can-i-stub-an-interface-method-using-moq). In my experience as long as your LINQ query can be compiled into SQL, then any logical unit tests you perform on the LINQ query using a regular list, should also hold true for the SQL query.

```
private IEnumerable<User> GetUsersWithNotices( DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, etc... )
{
    return UserRepository.FindAll( u => u.Active && !u.Whatever
                                        && u.JoinDate > minDate && u.JoinDate < maxDate
                                        && u.Notices.Any( n => n.Active && !n.Something
                                                               && Whatever
                                                               && etc... ) );
}
```

Comment: "a huge caveat is the fact that specific functions in your query may not be able to be converted to a SQL query..." This is exactly the problem I have. I can't separate the logic to test it because it confuses NHibernate too much.